# Highcharts: setting stroke-width on a line series when styledMode is on has no effect

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to set a specific line width on a line series, in a chart which has `styledMode` switched on.  (Styled mode is necessary for us, to eliminate in-line styles which are causing `Content-Security-Policy` errors.)

I find that the stroke color from my style is correctly applied to the line, but the `stroke-width` setting is ignored, even if I mark it as `!important`.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tsjLg95w/

You can edit the stroke value to prove that the style is being applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stroke is actually applied on a child path with the `highcharts-graph` class, which has a default `stroke-width` of 2px. Overriding the `stroke-width` on that class instead works (so your selector is `.series0Line .highcharts-graph`):

```
.series0Line .highcharts-graph {
  stroke-width: 30px;
  stroke: red;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7z8jx1y3/